# Check if two template template parameters are the same

Tags: c++

Is there a standard (`std`) way with which I can check two templates, not two template instantiations, for equality?

When I have two template template parameters, which I want to check for equality, ideally, I would like to write

```
template <template <class> class T1, template <class> class T2>
class Foo{
  static_assert(std::is_same<T1, T2>::value, "T1 and T2 must be same");
};
```

But can't, because [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) takes type template parameters and not template template parameters.

My current "solution" is that I instantiate with a random type (e.g. `void`) and then check for equality:

```
template <template <class> class T1, template <class> class T2>
class Foo{
  static_assert(std::is_same<T1<void>, T2<void>>::value, "T1 and T2 must be same");
};
```

This all nice and well until `T1` or `T2` cannot be instantiated with my chosen random type (here `void`).

I guess I could write my own type trait `is_same_template`, but I kinda want to get around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is not. But you can easily write your own trait:

```
template <template <typename...> typename, template <typename...> typename>
struct is_template_same : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> typename TT>
struct is_template_same<TT, TT> : std::true_type {};

template <template <typename...> typename TT, template <typename...> typename UU>
inline constexpr bool is_template_same_v = is_template_same<TT, UU>::value;
```

And then:

```
static_assert(is_template_same_v<T1, T2>, "T1 and T2 must be the same");
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it won't cover cases when the template has non-type arguments.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux And it also won't handle mixing types and non-types. And template template parameters. Like really, there should be some sort of "meta" parameter to avoid all this.

Comment: @Rakete111 Haha, I agree, C++ is ugly in that way.
You can't even have type and non-type templates with the same name.

Comment: @Jan15 I want to call them template template parameters, but that name is already taken :(

Comment: @Rakete1111 auto template parameter?

Comment: @Jan15 Wouldn't that be: `template <auto> struct foo;`?

Comment: @Rakete1111, love it, ship it ;)

Comment: @Jan15 Nope, `template <auto>` also already means something else: an unnamed non-type template parameter of any type.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised I don't see anything about general template parameters on the std-proposals discussion board.  It's not great, but out of the remaining language tokens, `?` seems best to me.  `template <? AnyParam>` or `template <? ... AnyParamsList>`.